# Add maven dependency issue

Tags: java, git, maven, github

I want to add a dependency in my pom.xml to checkout a libray from a github repository.

And my pom file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.nvtien.test</groupId>
<artifactId>tester</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.levonk</groupId>
        <artifactId>codequality</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cemerick-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/cemerick/cemerick-mvn-repo/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories></project>
```

Here is the github repository:

```
https://github.com/levonk/pub-maven-repo
```

My local ~m2/settings.xml

```
 <servers>
<server>
  <id>github</id>
  <username>XXXX</username>
  <password>XXXX</password>
</server></servers>
```

And i found an error by maven log:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tester: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.nvtien.test:tester:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   github.com/cemerick/cemerick-mvn-repo/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>    -> [Help 1]

My question is: What's going wrong ? Why maven can't download codequality-1.0.4.jar ?

Comment: Do you a local settings.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>https-levonk</id>
    <url>https://github.com/levonk/pub-maven-repo/tree/master/release/</url>
</repository>
```

BTW, I have found there only 1.0.8 (and 1.0.9) versions.

https://github.com/levonk/pub-maven-repo/tree/master/release/com/levonk/codequality

Please add the following dependency and it will work for you:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.levonk</groupId>
    <artifactId>codequality</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```